# Redirect email (add MX record) in AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain which is registered in GoDaddy. I configure AWS nameservers to manage the DNS records.

I need to configure e-mail redirect into Route 53. I tried this:

[image]

I want office@xxxxx.net to redirect e-mails to xxx@gmail.com by adding DNS MX record.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK that's not something DNS can do. The MX-Record should just define which Mailserver is responsible for accepting E-Mails for this domain. You can't use this to redirect specific e-mail addresses.

Comment: Ok, what I need to configure to forward e-mail?

Comment: You would have to configure the Gmail-Mailservers and then tell Gmail to accept E-Mails for your domain. Afterwards you'd need to configure the forwarding action withing Gmail. If Gmail supports a setup like this.... I don't know, but I'm not too optimistic.